# Save data before leave the page in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have asp.net page. 
I don't have button "Save" on it (not my requirement).

I need to save page data before I leave this page.

I've tried to do it with events like `Page_Unload` but it doen't work...
Cause `Save` method uses data from elements on page like `txtBox1.Text` I can't use `.ashx` handler to make some `ajax` save (Or I don't know how to use page elements in handler as they are `protected`).

So is there any solution except serealizing form and pass it to handler?

Comment: `Page_Unload` is a server-side event that gets fired (for simplicity) before your page gets sent to the browser.   Once your browser has received the html, the page no longer exists and `Page_Unload` will have already been called.  So no use here.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: @freedomn-m, thanks for explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `onbeforeunload` event. 
It should fire before unload. 
It allows you to ask back if the user really wants to leave. Check simillar example [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm).

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    return "You have attempted to leave this page.  If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
  }
</script>
```

In return you can save you required values.

Alternatively, you can send out an `Ajax` request when user leaves.

Comment: I've read about this js-event. But how can I make some call to method on page from this event?

Comment: you can get PageMethods. e.g. PageMethods.Message(OnGetMessageSuccess, OnGetMessageFailure);

Answer (score 0):

I know its late to answer , but its not late at all for people who is still working on same problem :
you just have to surround your execution function area with update panel like below

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="blahblahId"> 
 <ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button  CssClass="hidden" runat="server" ID="btnAddInfo" OnClick="execBforeUnload"/>                                                    
 </ContentTemplate>
           <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="btnAddInfo"/>                                      
              </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and your javascript code will be

```
  var unloadEvent = function (e)

    {
        alert("hi");
        __doPostBack("<%=btnAddInfo.ClientID%>", "");
    };
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", unloadEvent);
```

Finally your C# method will be as follows:

```
   public void execBforeUnload(object sender ,EventArgs e)
    {
        Session[lblNumber.Text] = null;
        Application[lblNumber.Text] = null;
    }
```